Recursively validate child records in oracle hierarchy query
I have table as below: source_t



Item_no
rec_code
rec_type
send_code
send_type
flag




10001
001
'FC'
0021
'SUP'
0


10001
002
'MA'
001
'FC'
0


10001
003
'MC'
001
'FC'
1


10001
001
'AB'
003
'MC'
0


10001
004
'KG'
001
'AB'
0


10002
001
'FA'
0031
'SUP'
0


10002
002
'MA'
001
'FA'
0


10002
003
'MC'
001
'FA'
0


10002
001
'AB'
003
'MC'
0


10002
004
'KG'
001
'AB'
0



My query is i need to pick all the records having sender type as SUP with flag as 0 for each item number and i need to match the receiver code and receiver type with sender code and sender type recursively and if any one child record has flag 1 for the particular item number (the child should some how connected to the parent) , then i need to show result as 1 for the sender type SUP.
The table is huge and it contains 100 million records with multiple child records for each item number.and there will be more than 50000 different item numbers
Output:



Item_no
rec_code
rec_type
send_code
send_type
flag




10001
001
'FC'
0021
'SUP'
1


10002
001
'FA'
0031
'SUP'
0




Use a correlated hierarchical query:
SELECT Item_no,
       rec_code,
       rec_type,
       send_code,
       send_type,
       CASE
       WHEN EXISTS(
              SELECT 1
              FROM   source_t x
              WHERE  flag = 1
              START WITH t.ROWID = x.ROWID
              CONNECT BY
                     PRIOR rec_code = send_code
              AND    PRIOR rec_type = send_type
              AND    PRIOR item_no  = item_no
            )
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END AS flag
FROM   source_t t
WHERE  send_type = 'SUP'
AND    flag      = 0

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE source_t (Item_no, rec_code, rec_type, send_code, send_type, flag) AS
SELECT 10001, '001', 'FC', '0021', 'SUP', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10001, '002', 'MA', '001',  'FC',  0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10001, '003', 'MC', '001',  'FC',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10001, '001', 'AB', '003',  'MC',  0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10001, '004', 'KG', '001',  'AB',  0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10002, '001', 'FA', '0031', 'SUP', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10002, '002', 'MA', '001',  'FA',  0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10002, '003', 'MC', '001',  'FA',  0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10002, '001', 'AB', '003',  'MC',  0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10002, '004', 'KG', '001',  'AB',  0 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



ITEM_NO
REC_CODE
REC_TYPE
SEND_CODE
SEND_TYPE
FLAG




10001
001
FC
0021
SUP
1


10002
001
FA
0031
SUP
0



fiddle
